# Run Stored Procedure From Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2013

I keep getting an error of

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is my vba I am using as well as my sql server stored procedure syntax.  What should I alter in order to have this run succesfully?

```
Private Sub btnRunStoredProc_Click()
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, startdate As String, enddate As String
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    startdate = "'" & Me.txtStartDate & "'"
    enddate = "'" & Me.txtEndDate & "'"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=Server;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "runstoredproc"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@startdate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, startdate)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@enddate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, enddate)
    cmd.Execute
End Sub


ALTER Procedure [dbo].[runstoredproc]
(
       @startdate varchar(100)
       ,@enddate varchar(100) 
)
As

Select * from helper where hiredate between @startdate And @enddate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `Format()` to convert MS Access dates to string as concatenating quotes will not work. Also, use `CONVERT()` to convert varchar strings to date in SQL Server. The format `YYYY-MM-DD` is used to not be dependent on cultural settings with placement of months and days.

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub btnRunStoredProc_Click()
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, startdate As String, enddate As String

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    startdate = Format(Me.txtStartDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    enddate = Format(Me.txtEndDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")

    With cmd
       .ActiveConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=Server;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
       .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
       .CommandText = "runstoredproc"
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@startdate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, startdate)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@enddate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, enddate)
       .Execute
    End With

    Set cmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

**TSQL**

```sql
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[runstoredproc]
(
       @startdate varchar(100)
       ,@enddate varchar(100) 
)
As

SELECT * FROM [helper]
WHERE hiredate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @startdate) AND CONVERT(DATE, @enddate)
```

Comment: This gives me a VBA error of query timeout.  I tried to add `.ActiveConnection.CommandTimeout = 0` but still shows error.

Comment: Why set it to zero seconds? Your query may be running longer than the default 30 seconds. Try adding `.commandTimeout = 60` in the `With` block for 60 seconds.

Comment: @Parfait - setting a timeout to zero means 'infinite timeout', not 'default timeout'.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason your parameters can't be date/time data type? What is the data type of your `hiredate` column? This has always worked for me:

```
Private Sub btnRunStoredProc_Click()
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, startdate As Date, enddate As Date
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    startdate = CVDate(Me.txtStartDate)
    enddate = CVDate(Me.txtEndDate)
    cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=Server;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "runstoredproc"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@startdate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , startdate)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@enddate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , enddate)
    cmd.Execute
End Sub


ALTER Procedure [dbo].[runstoredproc]
(
       @startdate datetime
       ,@enddate datetime 
)
As

Select * from helper where hiredate between @startdate And @enddate
```

Comment: Even if I alter to a datetime datatype I still receive the error query timeout

Comment: What if you run this sp manually in SQL Enterprise Manager? How long does it take? Can you do this from the same machine that you're running Access on, and with the same credentials?