# Run stored procedure with declared variable ms access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2013

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Pass_through_test", acViewNormal
    Me.Recalc
```

How would I include a variable that I have declared in SQL Server along with this line? So if my variable would be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Table_one]   
    @banana nvarchar(MAX)
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

And in the WHERE Clause of my SQL script I have:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_one WHERE Table_one.[banana] = @banana
```

What do I need to add to the VBA so that MS Access executes the procedure through a pass-through with a variable that is equal to @banana.

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818195/run-stored-procedure-from-access-vba?rq=1